# What is a catchy word that means (non-)self-descriptive

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm having fun with paradoxes, and I'm trying to come up with a catchy word for non-self-descriptive.  Maybe "autosemantic" fits the bill for self-descriptive (definitely open to other suggestions!), but I'm having a hard time negating it in a natural way.

For an example of the sentence I'm trying to construct:

> Is "inautosemantic" inautosemantic?

It just isn't flowing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for "[autological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological)"/"[homological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homological)" and their antonym "[heterological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterological)".

Comment: +1 Looks right to me. These aren't words to be used in every-day speech though. In formal writing however, they're great. :)

Comment: If I remember right, *heterological* was coined exactly for the sake of the paradox you describe :-)

Comment: @Noldorin: You clearly are not engaging in everyday speech with the right people.

Comment: @PLL It's called the Grelling-Nelson paradox, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox

Comment: I hope that's irony, else you've just made me very sad by a gross assumption.

Comment: So "English" is "autological", but "french" isn't ("francais" would have been, but it's not an English word).