# Words that define a type of word and also obey that definition

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a catchy word that means (non-)self-descriptive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/what-is-a-catchy-word-that-means-non-self-descriptive)

There are plenty of names for word sets:

- synonyms: words that have the same meaning
- palindromes: words that read the same forward or backwards
- homonyms: words that have the same spelling and different meaning
- metanyms: words that symbolize other larger concepts

But a certain set of words that define word sets are also in that set. Unfortunately, I can only think of one right now: *antonym*, which is in fact an antonym to the word *synonym*.

Do words like this have a name?

Comment: I might also need help retagging the question. I couldn't find anything really good.

Comment: Are you looking for "self-referential" words?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but out of scope on this site since we generally discourage list-type and discussion questions.

Comment: @KitFox - ok, then don't answer the list part. Do words like this have a technical name?

Comment: I've reduced the scope by removing the first question.

Comment: Also adjectival…

Comment: "Antonym" isn't that good an example, as a word is only an antonym with respect to some other word, not taken by itself.

Comment: @Jay But this is my point. Antonym can function as an antonym. So more generally I'm looking for all such WORDs such "WORD can function as a WORD" is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An ***autologous*** word is one that describes itself, such as *curt*, *sesquipedalian*, *recherché*, and *septisyllabically*.

And *autologous*. :)

Comment: No. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The OED lists *autological* with this meaning. Since the first citation (F.P.Ramsey, in 1926) was defining the word (for the purposes of a particular argument), this is a rare case in which one can reasonably say that *autological* is definitely the correct answer: that is the word which was coined specifically for that meaning.

*Autologous* is listed in the OED only with a medical meaning, and the first ten pages of results for googling "autologous" contain no non-medical examples.

Comment: Well, could I talk you into an *autonym*?